# Bind Request 0% Failure, Search Request 100% Failure?

Tags: ldap, jmeter

I have created a simple JMeter LDAP test .  The bind part works fine, but when I add a search request it fails with LDAP: error code 32... I supplied the same creds for the search request as I did the Bind so I am unsure why this is failing,  Below is some of the log file showing the successful binds and the failing search requests.  Is this happeneing because my ldap does not have CN's for the jmeter generated test users (cn=TestUser3600)?

```
1425907719464,0,unbind,0,Success,Thread Group 1-5,text,true,173,60,60,0
0,0,Search Request,500,javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'cn=TestUser3600',Thread Group 1-4,,false,0,62,62,0
1425907719497,0,unbind,0,Success,Thread Group 1-4,text,true,173,65,65,0
1425907719429,75,Bind,0,Success,Thread Group 1-55,text,true,231,66,66,0
1425907719405,129,Bind,0,Success,Thread Group 1-53,text,true,231,68,68,0
1425907719409,138,Bind,0,Success,Thread Group 1-54,text,true,231,70,70,0
```

Comment: You should add some more detail with the code and the nature of your directory server if anybody has a chance at helping you with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was supplying the wrong base DN, so everything after the bind was failing.